# Why don't some "for" commands work when the output is piped?

Tags: windows, batch-file

As an example of the problem I'm seeing, the command

```
for /D %%i in (*) do @if not exist m:\home\%%i echo %%i
```

gives me a list of directories in the current directory that don't exist in the other directory.

However, if I want to pipe the output to another command, for example:

```
(for /D %%i in (*) do @if not exist m:\home\%%i echo %%i) | findstr /n .
```

I get this error message:

```
echo was unexpected at this time.
```

Note that I can't just leave the brackets out, because that would result in the pipe operator being processed once per iteration of the loop; I need the output of the loop piped to a single instance of an application.  For example, if I leave the brackets out in this example, the line number from `findstr` will always be shown as 1 rather than counting the number of directories.

Does anybody know how to make this work, preferably in the general case rather than just this specific example?

Windows 7 SP1 x64.

Comment: In Windows 7, the parsed and reconstructed command line passed to `CreateProcessW` for the left-hand side is `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe  /S /D /c" ( FOR /D %i in (*) do @ if not existm:\home\%i echo %i )"`. Notice how it runs together `exist` and `m:\home\%i`. This is obviously a bug.

Comment: Try this for a workaround: `%ComSpec% /S /D /c "for /D %%i in (*) do @if not exist m:\home\%%i echo %%i" | findstr /n .`

Comment: @eryksun: d'oh!  Yes, that works perfectly, thanks.  If you'd like to repost your comments as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Given that first hint, I discovered another workaround:  `if not exist ^%space^% m:\home\%%i` where `%space%` has been defined to equal a space.  But yours is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Eryksun's comments, this is definitely a bug.  It can be worked around by explicitly creating a child process, rather than letting the batch processor do it for you:

```
cmd /s /c "for /D %%i in (*) do @if not exist m:\home\%%i echo %%i" | findstr /n .
```

Another option is to manually inject the missing space, by defining `%space%` to be a single space and saying:

```
(for /D %%i in (*) do @if not exist ^%%space^%% m:\home\%%i echo %%i) | findstr /n .
```

Comment: The first solution works for me, but not the second one (and I would be surprised when it work for anyone). As the `^%space^%` will be parsed in phase 1 to `^` ( as `space^` is an undefined variable) and then the caret is also dropped.

Comment: @jeb: thanks, looks like I messed up converting from the command-line version to the batch-file version.  Corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem of the parser with special `IF` syntax forms like:

> IF exist
>   IF defined
>   IF errorlevel
>   IF x EQU y

But this one works without problems

> IF x == y

It can be solved with defining a variable containing a single `IF`.

```
set "_IF_=IF"
( %%_IF_%% defined path echo It's defined ) | more
( %%_IF_%% errorlevel 0 echo Errorlevel is 0 or above ) | more
```

This works, as the `%%_IF_%%` will be expanded not before the child process parses the block.